# Changing line color of an Op Amp color

Tags: color, circuitikz, opamp

I was able to change the line color of op amp (to cyan) using the command shown in the code below for one circuit. However, I want to achieve the same affect for the whole document using a document wide setting instead of writing the code for every circuit but I could not. Any help would be appreciated.

```
node[op amp,color=cyan] (opamp)
```

Tash

Comment: Try `\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/.style={color=cyan}`

Comment: I tried @JohnKormylo approach but it did not work :(

Comment: If you would provide a MWE I would be able to test some of these WAGs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the target here --- having an MWE could help.

The color of the line of component is not one of the parameters of the class styling system (although the fill is, and the line thickness too). This is because depending on the component, the leads can be colored or not, and the final circuit may seem messy.

Anyway, if you insist, you can define a style. `op amp` is a node shape, not a style, but you can override it with a style. Being a node, it is defined at the upper `tikz` level, so this is a possible solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\tikzset{op amp/.style={shape=op amp, color=cyan}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \draw node[op amp](A){} (A.out) to[short,-o] ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \node[op amp]{};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can define your own different style:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\tikzset{cyan op amp/.style={op amp, color=cyan}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \draw node[cyan op amp](A){} (A.out) to[short,-o] ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \node[cyan op amp]{};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Although I find more pleasant the provided style:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{amplifiers/fill=cyan!30}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \draw node[op amp](A){} (A.out) to[short,-o] ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \node[op amp]{};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

...which will mix much better with the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks @Rmano. I understand what you said. In my circuit, resistors and capacitors are colored cyan so it makes sense to have the op amp outline colored as cyan (as opposed to cyan fill with black border.). Your first solution works perfectly well, so thanks for that. The only problem (which you alluded to also) is the leads are also colored cyan which should be black. Is there any way  the connecting (input and output) leads can be colored as black (I know I a being too picky :) ). 
(I wanted to attach my image of my circuit but could not find a way to do that).

Comment: No, that's the problem - for some component the leads are part of the shape, for others they are not, for historical (messy) reasons. To solve this would be a big job and disruptive for existing circuits. This is the reason why outline color is not in the styles.